# Passing Data to a tableViewController depending on button that was pressed

Tags: iphone, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, delegates

i'm a beginner in swift, but I do have a decent background in HTML,CSS, and some Java. I made this account to literally just ask this question, so i'll get straight to the point.

I really enjoy swift, but i've literally spent a f*cking week writing this same code over and over again, reviewing countless tutorials, books, guides, etc. To no avail; and i'm not going to lie, i'm getting reaaaaally tired of seeing 10+ errors stack up in my compiler as I keep trying to figure this out.

I have a ViewController, and I have a TableViewController - the ViewController being my home screen. On said viewController, I have two buttons, one is for BuildingItems, the other is BuildingBlocks. Both of which are segues.

on my TableViewController, I have buildBlocks and buildItems, both of which have their arrays defined.

What i'm trying to do, is depending on the button the user chose, I want that to then be the data that's used to populate my tableview. I can populate the tableview specifically by using the normal cell.textLabel?.text = arrayNameHere[indexPath.row] but obviously that doesn't solve my problem.

I hope that you're able to help me out here. I apologize for the crappy grammar and formatting, i've literally spent 4-5 hours a day this passed week trying to get this to work, and i've ended up just getting angry and deleting my entire project three different times. I'll include the code below. Again, excuse the formatting. I dont know why I can't seem to figure out swift, I keep trying every variation of delegate to try and pass something over that will let it work, but nothing is working.

**ViewController:**

```
@IBAction func BuildItems (_sender: Any) {
}

@IBAction func BuildBlocks (_sender: Any) {
}
```

**In TableViewController:**

```
    let buildItems = ["these are all my", "arrays for this"]

    let buildBlocks = ["same thing here","just saving time"]

    class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

        var myIndex = 0

        override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection: Int) -> Int {
        return buildItems.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell" for: indexPath)

        cell.textLabel?.text = buildItems[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        myIndex = indexPath.row

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need 1 segue: from the `ViewController` to the `TableViewController`.

In your `ViewController` make a variable for which button is pressed:

```
var category = ""
```

Change the value when a button is pressed, then segue:

```
@IBAction func BuildItems (_sender: Any) {
    category = "BuildItems"
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue", sender: self)
}

@IBAction func BuildBlocks (_sender: Any) {
    category = "BuildBlocks"
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue", sender: self)
}
```

Then in `prepare`:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "segue" {
        let vc = segue.destination as! TableViewController
        // Assuming you created a variable called sentCategory in the TableViewController
        vc.sentCategory = category
    }
}
```

In your `TableViewController` create an empty array:

```
let data = [String]()
```

In `viewDidLoad`:

```
if sentCategory == "BuildItems" {
    data = buildItems
} else {
    data = buildBlocks
}
```

Populate your `TableView` with the `data` variable.

A couple comments:

- Keep everything in your class scope, unless you have a good reason not to.
- You don't need delegates in this scenario. Pass data with a `prepare` function as shown above.

Comment: This worked! Thank you so damn much! Only thing, is that it performs two segues at once, i'm not quite sure why. I'm sure that's something I did though. Nonetheless -- thank you so much. This whole time I was trying to do things the hard way. One question - what's the difference between prepare and delegate? (in a more dumbed down version that a beginner can understand) Thank you!

Comment: Using the prepare function is the easiest way to pass data 1-way from 1 ViewController to another. Delegates can be used to pass data backwards or anywhere really. Basically a VC can conform to a protocol (delegate) and listen for changes. So 1 VC can call a method in another.

Answer (score 0):

Create bool var in your tableView controller maybe and helpArray

```
var dataArray:[String] = []
var isBuildItem:Bool = false
```

In your first controller implement prepareForSegue method like this:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let vc = segue.destination as? TableViewController {
             //set true or false it depends of which button you click
             vc.isBuildItem = //true or false
        }
}
```

Then in viewDidLoad in your TableViewController check bool variable

```
if(isBuildItem:Bool){
    dataArray = buildItems
}
else{
    dataArray = buildBlocks
}
```

In all your tableView delegate methods change buildItems array with dataArray

Answer (score 0):

in your ViewController:

```
import UIKit

var segueName = ""

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
    {
        segueName = segue.identifier!
        print(segueName)
    }

}
```

TableViewController:

```
import UIKit

class TableViewController: UITableViewController
{
    let animals = ["Cat","Dog","Mouse"]
    let colors = ["White","Blue","Red"]
    var arrayResult = [""]


    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if segueName == "seguebuttonA"
        {
            arrayResult = animals
        }
        else if segueName == "seguebuttonB"
        {
            arrayResult = colors
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int
    {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return arrayResult.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellTest", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

        // Configure the cell...

        cell.titleLabel.text = arrayResult[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }
}
```

Add segue name:
[image]

The complete example is in the link below, I hope I have helped, if you have any questions let me know.
https://github.com/cwilliams26/viewSegueTabelview/tree/master

Comment: I gave this a shot, it performed the segue, however, it brought me to a cell then another cell - both unpopulated. Not sure why. I still appreciate your time nonetheless!

Comment: Try to add your code to the question or the link so I can download your project for review.